# Vector operator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

With the help of Vector Operator $\nabla$ and the rules of differentiation and multiplication of vectors, prove the following identities:

$$grad (\varphi \psi) = \varphi grad(\psi) + \psi grad(\varphi)$$
$$div (\varphi \vec{A}) = \varphi \cdot div( \vec{A}) + \vec{A} \cdot div (\varphi)$$
$$curl (\varphi \vec{A}) = \varphi \cdot curl (\vec{A}) - \vec{A} \times grad(\varphi)$$

Thanks.

Comment: What doubts do you have? Did you try simply plugging these functions in the definitions of $\mathrm{grad}$, $\mathrm{div}$ and $\mathrm{curl}$ and using the basic properties of derivatives (for $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ functions)?

Comment: @DavideF At this point I have solved 1st and 2nd, but i still have confusion on 3rd how to begin with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the Levi-Civita symbol, this is a "proof" for the third one:
$$
\big(\mathrm{curl}\ (\varphi\vec A)\big)_i=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\varphi\vec A)_k=\\
=\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\varphi A_k)=\\
=\varepsilon_{ijk}(A_k\partial_j\varphi+\varphi\partial_jA_k)=\\
=\varepsilon_{ijk}(\partial_j\varphi)A_k+\varepsilon_{ijk}\varphi\partial_jA_k=\\
=\varepsilon_{ijk}(\partial_j\varphi)A_k+\varphi\varepsilon_{ijk}\partial_jA_k=\\
=(\mathrm{grad}\ \varphi\times\vec A)_i+(\varphi\ \mathrm{curl}\ \vec A)_i
$$
(using Einstein notation and $\partial_j=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}$ for brevity) so putting all three components together you get $\mathrm{curl}\ (\varphi\vec A)=\mathrm{grad}\ \varphi\times\vec A+\varphi\ \mathrm{curl}\ \vec A$.

Just remember that the vector product between $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ (two vectors in $\mathbb R^3$) can be defined by $(\vec v\times\vec w)_i=\varepsilon_{ijk}v_jw_k$, and that in cartesian coordinates you can write $\mathrm{curl}\ \vec f$ as $\nabla\times\vec f$, where $\nabla=\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}\big)=\big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\big)$.